# Zend Framework 2 routes

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I have one question or explanation to ask from you...

Im developing zf2 app and Im trying to make front/backend structure, so I add one more Module called Admin and now I want to make route structure like www.domain.com/[/:controller[/:action][/:id]]] frontend and www.domain.com/admin[/:controller[/:action][/:id]]];

so for frontend there is no problem and every thing is working great but in backend structure i always get "The requested URL could not be matched by routing." error.

My current module.config.php file is like this:

```
<?php
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'admin' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/admin/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'default' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/admin',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/admin[/:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'action' => 'index'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),

        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Admin\Controller\Index' => 'Admin\Controller\IndexController',
            'Admin\Controller\Login' => 'Admin\Controller\LoginController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
//            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'layout/admin'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/admin.phtml',
            'layout/login'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/login.phtml',
            'admin/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so i figure it out by myself;

I didn't understand routes;

So in admin/module.config.php
i was trying to set route to /admin/controller/action what i ended up doing was /admin/admin/controller/action

new config:

```
 'admin' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/admin',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                    'module' => 'admin',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '[/:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'module' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'module' => 'admin'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```